# Accidental similarity of irreducible representation and fundamental group of U(1)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, lie-groups

I have recently learned that all complex irreducible representations of U(1) are (1 dimensional) equivalents of $\rho_n(\exp(i\theta)) := \exp(in\theta)$. The tensor product of these representations satisfy $\rho_n \otimes \rho_m \sim \rho_{m+n}$ where $\sim$ denotes equivalence. This reminds me very much of the fundamental group of the circle which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and also U(1) as a manifold is of course the circle.

I was wondering if this similarity is just coincidence for U(1) or if there is some connection between the fundamental group (or other topological invariants of a Lie-group) and its irreducible representations.

Comment: In general the tensor product of two irreducible representations will not be irreducible again, nor is there necessarily an "inverse" to a given irreducible that you can tensor with it to get the trivial representation (the simplest argument here is just dimensional reasons), so irreducibles are not a group in this way. However if the group is abelian every irreducible is one-dimensional and the irreducibles form a group with the tensor product. This group is the same as the space of group homomorphisms $\widehat G:=Hom(G, U(1) )$, which is also known as the _Pontryagin dual_ of $G$ [...]

Comment: [...] I don't know any explicit connection between the fundamental group and the Pontryagin dual, but there definitely isn't some super powerful thing where one determines the other for example $\widehat{\Bbb R}=\Bbb R$, while $\Bbb R$ is contractible (ie has no homotopy information). Here is a link that discusses your specific question (why the dual of $U(1)$ is equal to its fundamental group) in more detail: https://mathoverflow.net/q/55575/55948